# php artisan migrate:reset ошибка

Tags: php, laravel, mvc

Хочу выполнить команду php artisan migrate:reset и есть ишибка  SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1832 Cannot change column 'role_id': used i
  n a foreign key constraint 'users_role_id_foreign' (SQL: ALTER TABLE users
  CHANGE role_id role_id INT DEFAULT NULL)

скрин ошибки -ь https://i.stack.imgur.com/oR0Vh.png

сама команда php artisan migrate работает отлично !
Кто может помогите пожалоста ;)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте в ваших миграциях добавить ->onDelete('cascade').
Что типа:

```
$table->foreign('role_id')
->references('id')->on('roles')
->onDelete('cascade');
```

Comment: такая же проблема

Comment: А можно сами миграции увидеть?